# cabal repl is too slow

Tags: haskell, cabal

Currently, `cabal repl` is unusable for me. Typing at the prompt is erratic: a few letters appear, then it seems to hang for 5-10 seconds, only to proceed again afterwards. I suspect it's related to the fact that it loads Alex/Happy generated files (81K and 134K respectively) into the REPL. I don't really need those files for REPL support  most of the time. I'm not sure if that's actually the problem, but I don't know what else to try.

I'd like to be able to exclude them from the REPL while still including them in the build process. Even better: can I only use one function from each of those files (`lex`/`parse`) somehow?

Edit: I'm seeing this behavior with GHC 7.8.3/Cabal 1.20.0.3 running on OS X 10.9 and a mid-2012 rMBP (Sandy Bridge) with 16GB of RAM. GHC/Cabal was installed via Homebrew.

Edit 2: [Cabal file](https://github.com/mattgreen/hython/blob/fde0872ce93493e0921c2df05abd18c5d8cc555c/hython.cabal) in question

Comment: Can you give some information on the machine you are running this on? Is it a local machine, a remote machine? OS? That type of stuff.

Comment: Added to original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried reorganizing the code per user5402's answer, but I wasn't able to get much of a speedup, even with code in different base packages.

Instead, I created a `.ghci` file in the project directory with the following contents:

```
:set -fobject-code
```

This loaded compiled versions of modules, with only the exported functions callable. For my uses, this is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Can you post your .cabal file?

If I understand your situation correctly, here's how I might proceed:

1. Verify that the alex and happy generated files are causing the slowdown.
2. If that is the case, consider moving them into a different package so that `ghci` will load the compiled versions of them.

For #1, I might try replacing the alex and happy generated files with just stubs - skeletal files which contain definitions (`= undefined`) for only the symbols which are imported by other modules.

Comment: Good idea! I will give that a try and report back. I'm not sure how to do #2, so I'll let you know if this fixes things.

Comment: I've confirmed that those generated files are causing a slowdown. I've also edited in a link to the current Cabal file. I put them into the `Hython.Parser` package, do I need to do anything special to prevent ghci from auto-loading them?